# react filepond to upload files to same server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Need help uploading files to production.
Followup instructions from https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond

On uploading the file, I get error-
POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) filepond.js:2608

I believe it is expecting some kinda of server to run and trigger upload. Please advise how can I upload files using filepond plugin. Also, how to make it run on production? For reactjs application, we just npm build and push the build files. Is there a action for uploading to production?

Comment: Did you check the 'Server' section on the Docs?

Answer (score 1):

The default React example will post multipart form data (file objects) to `"/api"`. If you set up a server at that location following the guidelines in the [server docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/) it should function correctly.

You can also use the server files used in the PHP boilerplate example: